# How to run a Parse background job locally

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to run a Parse background job locally instead of the Parse cloud. And I need the Node SDK because the browser SDK doesn't support use of the master key which this job needs.

Here is what I have tried in order to run the job locally :

```
var Parse = require('parse-cloud-express').Parse;

Parse.Cloud.job("myBackgroundJob", function(request, status) {

    status.success("Hello world!");

});
```

I have 2 issues :

1. I don't know how to actually run the job. I think the `Parse.Cloud.job` call only registers it. And I probably need to initialise the SDK (with API keys) in some way but I don't know how.
2. When I run this code it outputs `Running jobs is not supported in parse-cloud-express`, which leads me to believe that I might not be able to make it work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was much easier than I thought. I'll still post my solution in case it helps someone.

In order for it to work, you need a job called `myBackgroundJob` registered inside a `myBackgroundJobFile.js` file. You also need a `params.json` file containing the job parameters.

I'm using `eval()` instead of `require` because it allows me to use the file as is (meaning this file can also be used on Parse without modification).

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Parse = require('parse/node').Parse;
var BackgroundJobs = {}

var JobRequest = function (params) {
    this.params = params;
};
var JobStatus = function () {};
JobStatus.prototype.error = function () {};
JobStatus.prototype.message = function () {};
JobStatus.prototype.success = function () {};

Parse.Cloud.job = function (jobName, jobCall) {
    BackgroundJobs[jobName] = jobCall;
};
function callBackgroundJob(jobName, params) {
    var jobCall = BackgroundJobs[jobName];
    if (!jobCall) {
        console.error("There is no registered background job named `" + jobName + "`.");
        return Parse.Promise.error();
    } else {
        var request = new JobRequest(params);
        var status = new JobStatus();
        return jobCall(request, status);
    }
}

eval(fs.readFileSync('myBackgroundJobFile.js').toString());

Parse._initialize("APPLICATION_ID", "JAVASCRIPT_KEY", "MASTER_KEY");
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var params = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('params.json', 'utf8'));
callBackgroundJob("myBackgroundJob", params);
```

Comment: I'm curious, does this approach also work in the new parse server architecture?